# open file using only one information

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want juste to know how to open a file from my jsp page using servlet

I have juste this information of my file :

```
byte[] file= c.execute(connector, doc);
```

I want to know if I have juste this information  related to my file if is it possible or now to open a file

Comment: Opening a file from a JSP page is very bad practice, so I'd definitely ask what you're trying to achieve here.